# How to exclude a string in groovy using regex?

Tags: regex, groovy

I've got a string characters, such as XXXabcdacefgabcdcbefgabcdmn. I need to exclude the string "efg" from the original string and each item must start with "abcd" (so I cannot just use split simply).

Here is my sample code:

```
def str = "XXXabcdacefgabcdcbefgabcdmn"
def matcher = (str =~ /^\/(?!efg)([a-z0-9]+)$/)
//I just tried the solution searched from google but it don't work.
matcher.each {
     println it
}
```

The expected result should be:

```
abcdac
abcdcb
abcdmn
```

Any comment is very appreciated.

Comment: why don't you split the string with the pattern `/efg/` ?

Comment: Each items must begin with "abcd" or only the first?

Comment: Yes, each item should begin with "abcd", Thanks Casimir et Hippolyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def s = "XXXabcdacefgabcdcbefgabcdmn" 
def m = s =~ /abcd(?:(?!efg).)*/
(0..<m.count).each { print m[it] + '\n' }
```

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/YID9rO)

**Explanation**:

```
abcd        # 'abcd'
(?:         # group, but do not capture (0 or more times):
  (?!       #    look ahead to see if there is not:
    efg     #      'efg'
  )         #    end of look-ahead
  .         #    any character except \n
)*          # end of grouping
```

You could also split here:

```
def s = "XXXabcdacefgabcdcbefgabcdmn"
def m = s.split(/efg/)*.dropWhile { it != 'a' }
println m.join('\n')
```

Comment: Hi Hwnd, it works perfectly! Could you give me some explanation about the regex that you just wrote. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In other words `(?<=^|.|efg)` or `(?<=^|efg|.)` means `(?<!\n)`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to exclude the string "efg" from the original string and it should start with "abcd"

This might help you. Get matched group from desired index.

```
(abcd(.*?)(?=efg)|(?<=efg).*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pY9xF3/3)

---

OR try this one as well

```
(abcd(.*?)(?=efg|$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pY9xF3/2)

Sample code:

```
def str = "XXXabcdacefgabcdcbefgabcdmn" 
def matcher = str =~ /(abcd(.*?)(?=efg)|(?<=efg).*$)/
matcher.each {      println it[0] }
```

Comment: Thanks Braj, but I cannot sure how many "efg" characters are there.

Comment: Try it now. It should work. Try this one as well. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pY9xF3/2)

Comment: The result is 
[abcdac, abcdac, ac]
[abcdcb, abcdcb, cb]
[abcdmn, abcdmn, mn]
this is not what I want..but I still need to say thanks :).

Comment: As I said get it from index 0. As I did in my sample code.

Comment: I tested it [HERE](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5703128158568448) It should be `println it[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can use this pattern with a matcher:

```
(?:(?=abcd)|\G(?!\A)efg)((?:(?!efg).)*)
```

The substrings you need are in the first capturing group.

[**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uL3hH0/1)

An other way:

```
(?:(?=abcd)|\G(?!\A)efg)((?>[^e]+|e(?!fg))*)
```

[**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hV1wU1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something without using regex but pure tools provided by Groovy. :)

```
def str = "XXXabcdacefgabcdcbefgabcdmn"

assert ['abcdac', 'abcdcb', 'abcdmn'] == 
    str.split(/efg/).findAll { it.contains(/abcd/) }*.dropWhile { it != 'a' }
```